# Relatively simple question regarding if statement in Apex

Tags: apex

Beginner apex coder here so please be kind - ex Java coder

I'm currently trying to access a variable in the opportunity object that defined by the ID in the code I have

```
    Id oppId = calloutR.Params__c;

    if(Opportunity(Id = oppID).Submitted_Previously__C = True) {
    break;

    }
```

Essentially what I'm trying to do is check the opportunity object field for a "True" condition, then stop the method if it is.

I've looked around and I'm not sure about the syntax of defining the ID on the Opportunity object in order to reference the correct instance of the object.

So I was wondering - what is the correct notation for this?

Comment: Java and Apex are closely related in regards to structure. Remember to use your Java experience, and you'll have Apex down in no time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing assignment with comparison.

Assignment uses `=`
Comparison uses `==`

Also there are different ways to access the correct `sObject`.

If you have a `List`, you'll have to iterate the list and compare ids:

```
for (Opportunity opp : yourOppList){
  if (opp.Id == oppId && opp.Submitted_Previously__c){
    break;
  }
}
```

If a `Map` or `Set` you can do this:

```
if (oppMap.containsKey(oppId) && oppMap.get(oppId).Submitted_Previously__c){
  break;
}
```

Also you can dynamically access properties of the `sObject` using `get`, ie:

```
sObject.get('someproperty');
```

Hopefully this addresses your question.

Comment: And yeah, if you actually need to retrieve the object from the database, you'll need to use @sfdcfox 's syntax as well

Comment: Assignment uses `=` Comparison uses `==` is this different in Java?

Comment: Nope, but in the question, it's written incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

To get an existing object, you need to *query* for it, like this:

```
Opportunity[] records = [SELECT Submitted_Previously__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :oppId];
if(!records.isEmpty() && records[0].Submitted_Previously__c) {
  // Record was found, and was already submitted
```